# How many elements would have to searched in order to locate the integer 5215 at the 499th element and integer 7282 at the 686th element?

Tags: data-structures, array-algorithms

How many elements would have to be looked (binary search) at in order to find an integer 5215 at element 499 and an integer 7282 at element 686 assuming it's binary search algorithm and total number of elements in the array are 1000?

How would I go about solving my problem? I know this algorithm checks to see if an search value (or the element that I want to locate) is in the middle first by dividing the total number of elements of the array in half; however, if it's not there, it checks the upper half of the array, but if it's not there, it goes back down again. Also, here is my proof that I did research this problem before attempting to ask the question which is embedded in the HTML code.

I do have a theory though (see my theory below:)

1000/2 = the first element is 500 element

500/2, the next element is 250 element.

Comment: @Will I do know that there are 0-999 indexes in the 1000 element array so is that a start to understanding first?

Comment: Binary search assumes that the array is sorted. In your example, the array can't be sorted in ascending order, because the item at 499 is larger than the item at 686. Is the array sorted in descending order? If the array is not sorted, then binary search won't work.

Comment: @Jim Mischel How about if 499 index is 5215 and 686 index is 7282? Sorry about that.

Comment: With a pencil and paper, go through the steps described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure. Write down your work for each step. You'll find your answer in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @  Jim Mischel In my mind it kinda makes sense, but is it possible to draw a clear (colored)visual representation to see how this work in theory. How it would look at the lower and upper halves of 1000?

Comment: @Jim Mischel  So for the 499th element, it would be like this for the number of comparisons: 500->250->375->437->468->484->492->496->498->499 and for the 686, it would like for the number of comparsions: 500->750->625->687->656->672->680->684->686

Comment: @Shivansh Singh Am right, right!

Answer (score -1):

Your question seems mysterious but I can help you with binary search algorithm if you need help in it.

Binary search algorithm works when your array is sorted that is in ascending or descending order.

This algorithm access your middle element of array at first iteration and if the element is not at n/2 in even case or n+1/2 in odd length case the algorithm will check if the search element is bigger or smaller , if it is smaller lower half is accessed and if it is bigger than upper half of array is accessed. This is the case when array is sorted in ascending order.

And for time complexity it gives you worst case scenario as O(log n). Where n is the number of elements in array that is length of array.

Hope I helped.